# Check for matching key in array, if found take 2nd array entries if not take 1st array entries in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Im having 2 array object

1.

```json
itemMapping = {
    id:1,
    hierarchyDesc:"Men's casual",
    style:"Denim Pants",
    styleDesc:"VS pants",
    color:"blue"
}
```

2. 

```json
mapData = {
    hierarchyDesc:"Women's casual",
    style:"Cotton Pants",
    styleDesc:"pants"
}
```

I need to compare each itemMapping's key with each mapData's key and form an newArray,
if any of keys are matching, (for ex: here in itemMapping and mapData - hierarchyDesc, style, styleDesc are there in both) then take those matching objects entries from mapData array and push to newArray,
if its not matching and is only in itemMapping array then take those not matching object entries from itemMapping array and push to newArray.

Note: all the object key of mapData will be present in itemMapping but vice versa is not true.

expected result:

```json
newArray = {
    id:1,
    hierarchyDesc:"Women's casual",
    style:"Cotton Pants",
    styleDesc:"pants",
    color:"blue"
}
```

how can I achieve it in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ES6 spread operator `const res = {...itemMapping, ...mapData  }`

See below

```js
const itemMapping = { id:1, hierarchyDesc:"Men's casual", style:"Denim Pants", styleDesc:"VS pants", color:"blue" },
mapData = { hierarchyDesc:"Women's casual", style:"Cotton Pants", styleDesc:"pants" };
const res = {...itemMapping, ...mapData  }
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map over the keys of the `itemMapping` object and use `Object.fromEntries` to convert the array of key-value pairs to an object.

```js
const itemMapping = { id:1, hierarchyDesc:"Men's casual", style:"Denim Pants", styleDesc:"VS pants", color:"blue" },
mapData = { hierarchyDesc:"Women's casual", style:"Cotton Pants", styleDesc:"pants" };
const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(itemMapping)
    .map(k => [k, k in mapData ? mapData[k] : itemMapping[k]]));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something similar to this.

```
const newValues = {};
for (const item in itemMapping) {
    if(mapData[item]){
        newValues[item] = mapData[item]
    } else {
        newValues[item] = itemMapping[item]
    }
}
```

The required key values get added to newValues object (not an array)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the above approach is to use an array reduce on the keys in `itemMapping`. Note that I would also consider renaming `newArray` to something else as it is an object not an array.

```js
const itemMapping = {
  id: 1,
  hierarchyDesc: "Men's casual",
  style: "Denim Pants",
  styleDesc: "VS pants",
  color: "blue"
};

const mapData = {
  hierarchyDesc: "Women's casual",
  style: "Cotton Pants",
  styleDesc: "pants"
};

const newArray = Object.keys(itemMapping).reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = key in mapData ? mapData[key] : itemMapping[key];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newArray)
```